# Reading from Pipe in C

Tags: c, file, pipe, fork

I have a program that reads from a Random Access File and is to return the smallest and largest number in the file. One requirement is that this is done with 4 processes using fork() and piping the results. I divide the file up into 4 chunks and have each process evaluate a chunk of the file. I find the max and min of each chunk and write them to a pipe. At the end I will compare the piped values and find the largest and smallest of the values.

I am having trouble reading from the pipes as they are returning -1. Any insight on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int findMin(int start, int end, const char * filename);
int findMax(int start, int end, const char * filename);

//Calculates minimum and maximum of a number
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{   

   const char * filename;  // name of file to read
   FILE * ft;  // file handle for the file
   int pid,    // process id of this process
       num,    // the number of integer values in the file
       i,      // loop control variable for reading values
       temp=0; // used to store each value read from the file
   long size;  // size in bytes of the input file
   /*********************************************************************/

   filename = argv[1];  // read the file named on the command line

   ft= fopen(filename, "rb");
   if (ft) 
   {
       pid = getpid();
       fseek (ft,0,SEEK_END); //go to end of file
       size = ftell(ft);      //what byte in file am I at?
       fseek (ft,0,SEEK_SET); //go to beginning of file
       num = (int)size / (int)sizeof(int); // number of integer values
       printf("file size: %li bytes\n", size);
       printf("sizeof(int) = %i bytes\n",(int) sizeof(int));
       printf("how many integers = %i\n\n", num);

       fclose(ft);
   }

       //Split file size into quarters to make 4 processes
       int increment = num/4;
       int num1 = increment;
       int num2 = num1 + increment;
       int num3 = num2 + increment;
       int num4 = num;

       int status;

       int pid1 = -1;
       int pid2 = -1;

       //Pipes
       int fdmin1[2];
       int fdmax1[2];

       int fdmin2[2];
       int fdmax2[2];

       int fdmin3[2];
       int fdmax3[2];

       int fdmin4[2];
       int fdmax4[2];

       //initializing pipes
       if(pipe(fdmin1) == -1)
       {
           perror("Piping fd1 failed");
           return 0;
       }
       if(pipe(fdmax1) == -1)
       {
           perror("Piping fd2 failed");
           return 0;
       }

       if(pipe(fdmin2) == -1)
       {
           perror("Piping fd3 failed");
           return 0;
       }
       if(pipe(fdmax2) == -1)
       {
           perror("Piping fd4 failed");
           return 0;
       }

       if(pipe(fdmin3) == -1)
       {
           perror("Piping fd3 failed");
           return 0;
       }
       if(pipe(fdmax3) == -1)
       {
           perror("Piping fd4 failed");
           return 0;
       }

       if(pipe(fdmin4) == -1)
       {
           perror("Piping fd3 failed");
           return 0;
       }
       if(pipe(fdmax4) == -1)
       {
           perror("Piping fd4 failed");
           return 0;
       }

       //temp variables for pipes
       int temp1;
       int temp2;
       int temp3;
       int temp4;
       int temp5;
       int temp6;
       int temp7;
       int temp8;


       pid1 = fork();
       printf("pid1: %d \n", pid1);

       if(pid1 > 0)
       {
           //Process 1
           temp1 = findMin(0, num1, filename);
           temp2 = findMax(0, num1, filename);

           close(fdmin1[0]);
           if(write(fdmin1[1], &temp1, sizeof(int)) == -1)
           {
               printf("Error writting to pipe");
           }
           close(fdmin1[1]);
           close(fdmax1[0]);
           if(write(fdmax1[1], &temp2, sizeof(int)) == -1)
           {
               printf("Error writting to pipe");
           }
           close(fdmax1[1]);
       }
       else if(pid1 == 0)
       {
           //Process 2
           temp3 = findMin(num1, num2, filename);
           temp4 = findMax(num1, num2, filename);

           close(fdmin2[0]);
           if(write(fdmin2[1], &temp3, sizeof(int)) == -1)
           {
               printf("Error writting to pipe");
           }
           close(fdmin2[1]);
           close(fdmax2[0]);
           if(write(fdmax2[1], &temp4, sizeof(int)) == -1)
           {
               printf("Error writting to pipe");
           }
           close(fdmax2[1]);

           pid2 = fork();
           printf("pid2: %d \n", pid2);
           if(pid2 > 0)
           {
               //Process 3
               temp5 = findMin(num2, num3, filename);
               temp6 = findMax(num2, num3, filename);

               close(fdmin3[0]);
               if(write(fdmin3[1], &temp5, sizeof(int)) == -1)
               {
                   printf("Error writting to pipe");
               }
               close(fdmin3[1]);

               close(fdmax3[0]);
               if(write(fdmax3[1], &temp6, sizeof(int)) == -1)
               {
                   printf("Error writting to pipe");
               }
               close(fdmax3[1]);

           }
           else if(pid2 == 0)
           {
               //Process 4
               temp7 = findMin(num3, num4, filename);
               temp8 = findMax(num3, num4, filename);

               close(fdmin4[0]);
               if(write(fdmin4[1], &temp7, sizeof(int)) == -1)
               {
                   printf("Error writting to pipe");
               }
               close(fdmin4[1]);

               close(fdmax4[0]);
               if(write(fdmax4[1], &temp8, sizeof(int)) == -1)
               {
                   printf("Error writting to pipe");
               }
               close(fdmax4[1]);
           }

       }

       //Close all pipe ends in all processes
       close(fdmin1[0]);
       close(fdmin1[1]);
       close(fdmin2[0]);
       close(fdmin2[1]);
       close(fdmin3[0]);
       close(fdmin3[1]);
       close(fdmin4[0]);
       close(fdmin4[1]);

       close(fdmax1[0]);
       close(fdmax1[1]);
       close(fdmax2[0]);
       close(fdmax2[1]);
       close(fdmax3[0]);
       close(fdmax3[1]);
       close(fdmax4[0]);
       close(fdmax4[1]);

       //Wait for all processes to finish
       int returnStatus;    
       waitpid(pid1, &returnStatus, 0);

       int returnStatus2;    
       waitpid(pid2, &returnStatus2, 0);

       //Make sure we are in parant process
       if(pid1 > 0)
       {
           //Variables to compare min and max returned from processses
           int min1;
           int max1;
           int min2;
           int max2;
           int min3;
           int max3;
           int min4;
           int max4;

           //read from pipe (error is occuring here)
           close(fdmin1[1]);
           if(read(fdmin1[0], &min1, sizeof(int)) == -1)
           {
               printf("Error reading");
           }
           close(fdmin1[0]);
           printf("min1: %d \n", min1);
       }



   return 0;

}

//function to find the minimum in the file
int findMin(int start, int end, const char * filename)
{
   int temp;
   int smallestNum;
   int i;
   int length = end - start;

   FILE * ft2;
   ft2= fopen(filename, "rb");
   fseek (ft2,start,SEEK_SET);

   fread(&smallestNum,sizeof(int),1,ft2);

   for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
       fread(&temp,sizeof(int),1,ft2);

       //printf("%d \n", temp);

       if(temp < smallestNum)
       {
           smallestNum = temp;
       }
       /*
       printf("%5i: %7i  ",pid,temp);
       if ((i+1)%5 == 0) 
           printf("\n");
       */
   }

   fclose(ft2);
   printf("SmallestNum: %d \n", smallestNum);

   return smallestNum;
}

//function to find maximum in file
int findMax(int start, int end, const char * filename)
{
   int temp;
   int largestNum;
   int i;
   int length = end - start;

   FILE * ft3;
   ft3= fopen(filename, "rb");
   fseek (ft3,start,SEEK_SET);

   fread(&largestNum,sizeof(int),1,ft3);

   for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
       fread(&temp,sizeof(int),1,ft3);

       //printf("%d \n", temp);

       if(temp > largestNum)
       {
           largestNum = temp;
       }
       /*
       printf("%5i: %7i  ",pid,temp);
       if ((i+1)%5 == 0) 
           printf("\n");
       */
   }

   fclose(ft3);
   printf("Largest Num: %d \n", largestNum);

   return largestNum;
}
```

Here is the code for generating the Random Access File

```
/*
 * This file generates a binary output file containing integers. It
 * requires the output filename as a parameter and will take an 
 * argument indicating the number of values to generate as input.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BIAS 0 // a bias value added to the numbers to "bias" the file 
               // contents to provide an offset to the min and max

 int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    const char * filename;   // name of the output file
    FILE * ft;               // file handle for output file
    int numtogen = 1000000;  // default is to generate 1,000,000 numbers
    int randomnum, i; // variables used in the loop generating numbers

    if (argc<2) {  // not enough arguments, need output file name
        printf("Usage: gendata <filename> [number of numbers]\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc == 3)  // optional third argument for number of numbers 
        numtogen = atoi(argv[2]);

    filename=argv[1];  // use the filename entered to store numbers
    srand(time(NULL)); // seed the random number generator
    ft= fopen(filename, "wb") ;
    if (ft) {
        for (i = 0; i < numtogen; i++){
            randomnum = rand() % numtogen + BIAS;
            fwrite(&randomnum,sizeof(int),1,ft);
        }
        fclose(ft);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am having trouble reading from the pipes as they are returning -1. Any insight on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

this is because in the *main* process you close two times the pipe, doing

> ```
> printf("pid1: %d \n", pid1);
>
> if(pid1 > 0)
> {
>    ...
>    close(fdmin1[0]);         <<< HERE
> ```

and

> ```
> //Close all pipe ends in all processes
> close(fdmin1[0]);            <<< HERE
> ```

so it is closed when you do :

> ```
> if(read(fdmin1[0], &min1, sizeof(int)) == -1)
> ```

do not close `fdmin1[0]` before to read in but the reverse.

Note you also close two times `fdmin1[1]` and `fdmax1[0]` and `fdmax1[1]`.

The usage of the pipes is very strange and probably no what you want :

- `fdmin1` is a pipe between the *main* process and itself, the *main* process does `if(write(fdmin1[1], &temp1, sizeof(int)) == -1)`and later `if(read(fdmin1[0], &min1, sizeof(int)) == -1)` so that pipe is useless and `min1` is `temp1`
- the *main* process does `if(write(fdmax1[1], &temp2, sizeof(int)) == -1)` but nobody read that value, that pipe is useless and `temp2 = findMax(0, num1, filename);` is done for nothing.
- the *main* process child does `if(write(fdmin2[1], &temp3, sizeof(int)) == -1)` and `if(write(fdmax2[1], &temp4, sizeof(int)) == -1)` and `if(write(fdmin3[1], &temp5, sizeof(int)) == -1)` and `if(write(fdmax3[1], &temp6, sizeof(int)) == -1)` but nobody read, these four pipes are useless and all the min/max computing are done for nothing.
- it is the same for the third created process doing `if(write(fdmin4[1], &temp7, sizeof(int)) == -1)` and `if(write(fdmax4[1], &temp8, sizeof(int)) == -1)` but nobody read, these two pipes are useless and the min/max computing are done for nothing.

That means at the end you do not get the right min/max value in the *main* process, but only the min value of the first quarter computing by the *main* process and all other computing are lost.

The code

> ```
>   //Wait for all processes to finish
>   int returnStatus;    
>   waitpid(pid1, &returnStatus, 0);
>
>   int returnStatus2;    
>   waitpid(pid2, &returnStatus2, 0);
> ```

is executed by all the child processes, because you do not `exit` or `return` when you have to do.

You also have an undefined behavior because you have a race condition between your processes, the execution is not the same depending on where I had `usleep` in your code. A parent process must wait for the end of its child process when needed, you do not at the right moment. Note your process numbering is wrong, there are only the *main* process and two children, so 3 processes rather than 4, `//process4` does not exist and that comment is in process 2.

Except in the *main* process you do not read from the right position in the file because for *findMin* and *findMax* the parameter *start* correspond to a rank of *int* rather than a position in the file, you must replace

> ```
> fseek (ft2,start,SEEK_SET);
> fseek (ft3,start,SEEK_SET);
> ```

by

```
 fseek (ft2,start*sizeof(int),SEEK_SET);
 fseek (ft3,start*sizeof(int),SEEK_SET);
```

You also (try to) read one *int* too many doing

> ```
> int length = end - start;
> ...
> fread(&smallestNum,sizeof(int),1,ft2);
>
> for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
> {
>    fread(&temp,sizeof(int),1,ft2);
> ```

for instance replace the loop to have

```
for(i = 1; i < length; i++)
```

There also are a lot of useless variables in your program, if I compile with option `-Wall` :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ gcc -Wall -g p.c -o p
p.c: In function ‘main’:
p.c:250:16: warning: unused variable ‘max4’ [-Wunused-variable]
            int max4;
                ^
p.c:249:16: warning: unused variable ‘min4’ [-Wunused-variable]
            int min4;
                ^
p.c:248:16: warning: unused variable ‘max3’ [-Wunused-variable]
            int max3;
                ^
p.c:247:16: warning: unused variable ‘min3’ [-Wunused-variable]
            int min3;
                ^
p.c:246:16: warning: unused variable ‘max2’ [-Wunused-variable]
            int max2;
                ^
p.c:245:16: warning: unused variable ‘min2’ [-Wunused-variable]
            int min2;
                ^
p.c:244:16: warning: unused variable ‘max1’ [-Wunused-variable]
            int max1;
                ^
p.c:48:12: warning: unused variable ‘status’ [-Wunused-variable]
        int status;
            ^
p.c:20:8: warning: unused variable ‘temp’ [-Wunused-variable]
        temp=0; // used to store each value read from the file
        ^
p.c:19:8: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
        i,      // loop control variable for reading values
        ^
p.c:17:8: warning: variable ‘pid’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int pid,    // process id of this process
        ^
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$
```

Out of that

- You must check the value of *argc* before to do `filename = argv[1];`.
- If `fopen(filename, "rb");` fails you must stop the execution, currently you continue with an undefined behavior.
- Note also your program can be simplified using array of pipe rather than separated variables for them, allowing you to use a loop rather than the sequence of `if(pipe(fdmin1) == -1) ... if(pipe(fdmax4) == -1) ...`. It is the same to start the child processes, rather than to duplicate the code use a function to write it only one time. Doing that you can have a definition allowing any number of child process rather than dedicated to 4 only.

---

Going back to the statement

> I divide the file up into 4 chunks and have each process evaluate a chunk of the file

This is an extreme case but you have to manage the case the file is too small to be divided by 4, this is not the case in your proposal.

> this is done with 4 processes

Considering the *main* process is count among the 4, 3 children must be created. But rather than to have each child creating an other one if needed, it is more simple to have the 3 children created by the *main* process and the parallelism is a little better.

A program must be *simple*, I already said you have a lot of variables for nothing and lot of code is duplicated, also :

- It is useless to have so many pipes, only one is enough to allow each child to send the min/max it computed because the pipe reads and writes are guaranteed to be atomic up to `PIPE_BUF` (larger than the size of 2 `int`)
- It is useless to read the file so many times, you can search for the min and the max at the same time.

And finally a proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define N 4 /* including the main process */

/* to send/receive result atomicaly through the pipe */
typedef struct {
  int min, max;
} MinMax;

void findMinMax(long offset, long n, FILE * fp, MinMax * minmax);

//Calculates minimum and maximum of a number
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{   
  const char * filename;  // name of file to read
  FILE * fp;   // file handle for the file
  long num;    // the number of integer values in the file
  long size;   // size in bytes of the input file
  long offset; // offset in file
  int pp[2];   // the unique pipe
  int pids[N-1];
  MinMax minmax;
  int i; 

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", *argv);
    exit(-1);
  }

  filename = argv[1];

  fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("cannot open file");
    exit(-1);
  }

  /* get file size */
  if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) == -1) { //go to end of file
    perror("cannot fseek");
    fclose(fp); /* also done automaticaly when exiting program */
    exit(-1);
  }

  size = ftell(fp);      //what byte in file am I at?
  num = size / sizeof(int); // number of integer values

  printf("file size: %li bytes\n", size);
  printf("how many integers = %li\n\n", num);

  if (num < N) {
    fprintf(stderr, "the input file is too small, it must contains at least %i int\n", N);
    fclose(fp); /* also done automaticaly when exiting program */
    exit(-1);
  }

  //initializing pipe
  if(pipe(pp) == -1) {
    perror("Piping failed");
    exit(-1);
  }

  offset = 0;

  for (i = 0; i != N-1; ++i) {
    pids[i] = fork();

    switch (pids[i]) {
    case 0:
      /* child */
      {
        FILE * fp2 = fopen(filename, "rb");

        if (fp2 == NULL) {
          perror("child cannot open file");
          exit(-1);
        }

        findMinMax(offset, num/N, fp2, &minmax);
        printf("min max child %d : %d %d\n", i, minmax.min, minmax.max);
        if (write(pp[1], &minmax, sizeof(minmax)) != sizeof(minmax)) {
          perror("Error writting to pipe");
          exit(-1);
        }
      }
      exit(0);
    case -1:
      /* parent */
      perror("Cannot fork");
      exit(-1);
    default:
      /* parent, no error */
      offset += (num/N)*sizeof(int);
    }
  }

  findMinMax(offset, (size - offset)/sizeof(int), fp, &minmax);
  printf("min max main : %d %d\n", minmax.min, minmax.max);

  for (i = 0; i != N-1; ++i) {
    int status;
    MinMax mm;

    if ((waitpid(pids[i], &status, 0) != -1) &&
        (status == 0) &&
        (read(pp[0], &mm, sizeof(mm)) == sizeof(mm))) {
      if (mm.min < minmax.min)
        minmax.min = mm.min;
      if (mm.max > minmax.max)
        minmax.max = mm.max;
    }
    else
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot get result for child %d\n", i);
  }

  printf("global min max : %d %d\n", minmax.min, minmax.max);
  return 0;
}

// function to find the minimum and maximum in the file
// n > 1
void findMinMax(long offset, long n, FILE * fp, MinMax * minmax)
{
  int v;

  if (fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
    perror("cannot fseek");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (fread(&minmax->min, sizeof(minmax->min), 1, fp) != 1) {
    fclose(fp); /* also done automaticaly when exiting program */
    perror("cannot read int");
    exit(-1);
  }
  minmax->max = minmax->min;

  while (--n) {
    if (fread(&v, sizeof(v), 1, fp) != 1) {
      fclose(fp); /* also done automaticaly when exiting program */
      perror("cannot read int");
      exit(-1);
    }

    if (v < minmax->min)
      minmax->min = v;
    if (v > minmax->max)
      minmax->max = v;
  }

  fclose(fp); /* also done automaticaly when exiting program */
}
```

As you can see the code is much simple and I just have to modify `#define N 4` to an other value to change the number of processes working in parallel.

Using your second program to generate 1000000 `int` in *aze*, compilation and execution of my proposal :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ gcc -g -Wall p.c
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out aze
file size: 4000000 bytes
how many integers = 1000000

min max main : 2 999995
min max child 0 : 10 999994
min max child 2 : 0 999998
min max child 1 : 3 999999
global min max : 0 999999
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Really helped understand better whats going on. I put the numbers from the random access file into a text editor and search for the max and min I get from the proposal you gave me. I can't find the max sometimes depending on how many processes I use for 'N'. Do you happen to know why this behavior may be happening?

Comment: @Erck I am not sure to understand you, if the number are not in binary (using a constant size) but in a textual form their size is not constant, so it is not possible to use `fseek` to read from a given offset because you are not able to know the offsets to use